# Zero or many association in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails  and writing an application which has  two models `job` and `sub_job`
In my application job can have either `zero` , `one` or many `sub_jobs`

The has_many association will create one to many relationship for `jobs`.

I have written the following in the respective models

```
#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sub_jobs
end

#app/models/sub_job.rb
class SubJob < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :job
end
```

Now it means a `job` can have multiple `sub_jobs` but my question is:

> Will has_many association  handle the case when there is no subjob for a particular job ?

Comment: Yes it will handle that situation. Think of the simple one `Article` has many `Comments` example. Creating an instance of Article, does not rely on any Comments, however your Article is free to have as many Comments you want.

Comment: Just to mention, as you're a learner, that for this particular situation you might use one Job class, as you can have: "has_many :subjobs, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => :parent_job_id".

Answer (score 4):

yes, absolutely.  If you wanted to ensure that there was at least one job, you'd put in a validation in the Job model.

```
validates :sub_jobs, :presence => true
```

But in your case you don't need that, so you don't put it in.

Any Job records without SubJob records associated will simply return an empty array...

```
p my_job.sub_jobs
=> []
```

Answer (score 1):

> Will has_many association handle the case when there is no subjob for
>   a particular job ?

Short answer: `yes`

--

Long answer:

Rails isn't a magic wizard, it's simply a [layer of abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) for dealing with requests & relational databases.

This means that if you have a `has_many` association, what you're *really* telling Rails is to use SQL to look up any references to the original model in the associated table.

[image]

[You can read more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association).

It does not mean you *have* to have "many" instances of an associated record, or even that you have to have any at all. It simply means Rails will look up any associated records with the corresponding [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in the related table.

For example...

```
#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    # columns id | title | description | created_at | updated_at
    has_many :sub_jobs
end

#app/models/sub_job.rb
class SubJob < ActiveRecord::Base
    # columns id | job_id | title | etc 
    belongs_to :job
end
```

The `job_id` column is the foreign_key, thus is what Rails will use to look up any corresponding records.

You can then do this:

```
#app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ActionController::Base
   def show
      @job = Job.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/jobs/show.html.erb
<% if @job.sub_jobs.any? %>
   <% @job.sub_jobs.each do |sub| %>
       <%= sub.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If no associated sub_jobs exist, it will just not put anything out.